# How to output 5th integer from an 8 integer long input? Then tell if 5th integer is even or odd?c++

Tags: c++, output

I'm quite new to c++ and I was not sure how I could output the 5th integer from an 8 integer input? Here is what I have so far:

```
using namespace std;
void main()
{
int SID, i, x ;

cout << "Pleas enter 8 digits :";
cin  >> SID;

cout << "The 5th digit is : " << x << endl;

for (SID = i; i < 10; i++);
if  (x % 2 = 0) { cout << "It is even number."; }

    else { cout << "It is odd number."; }
```

As you can see I want to use x as the 5th integer but I am not sure how to code that. I know that using modulus division will determine if the 5th integer is even/odd. I know that using a loop here is mandatory and decided to use a for loop but I feel I did not input it correctly.

Comment: Hint: the `for` loop does nothing for you. Try placing the `cin >> SID` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just quickly, becuase I am getting the feeling you are very new to this... I think you need to rethink your question and answer...

Few things to try and think about:

1. Do you want the user to enter a number (int) with 8 digits? If so then think of what operations you need to perform on 12345678 to get the 5th number.
2. Do you want the user to enter 8 numbers? If so you will need to store each one of them... If you know where you store them, you know where to go looking for the 5th one. No?
3. Using a for loop could be useful, but what for? I am not sure if you know what are you trying to use it for? Why did you chose i<10?
4. Maybe make sure you understand what loops do and how to use them.

Overall you should probably break the problem down and ask specific questions. I don't think this is the place for us to solve your entire problem. Also, I have a feeling that once you break your question down to more specific things the answers would already be on StackOverflow somewhere.

Also as owacoder mentioned it might be a good idea to place the cin >> SID inside a loop.